# vim open existing files

Tags: vim

When I want to open a existing file (I use vim filename.java), it seems that I create a new file. Because it says new file. And there is no code.

I don't know why. Can the command vim filename.java open any file in the computer? Should I put my file into a particular place?

Comment: by typing that, you open a file in **current** directory

Comment: *Can the command vim filename.java open any file in the computer?* Yes. But that command will only open files in the current directory. *Should I put my file into a particular place?* Probably.

Answer (score 0):

Try to search for your file using a number of ways like:

```
$ locate filename.java
```

if it doesn't work, try also find

```
$ find filename.java
```

(note: you don't have to write the the "$", it's there to mark the start of the command line)

The commands above will give you an output similar to:

```
/home/jane/FOLDER/FOLDER/FOLDER/filename.java
```

To edit, write:

```
$ vim /home/jane/FOLDER/FOLDER/FOLDER/filename.java
```

Remember to save after edit!